# Convert multiple values ​from a string to php json

Tags: php

I am trying to get results when converting a url to json. I thank those who can help me, thank you.

**I have this string:** id_user123=123;456;789&id_user456=333;545;908

**I would like to get this result:**

```
{"result": [
{"id_user123":[ "123", "456", "789" ] },
{"id_user456":[ "333", "545", "908" ] }
]}
```

Comment: Please show us your current implementation, even if it is only partially done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parse_​url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the "query" part of your string
and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get each parameter and values.

```
<?php

$url = 'test.php?id_user123=123;456;789&id_user456=333;545;908';
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $queryArray);

$result = [];
foreach ($queryArray as $userId => $values) {
    $result['result'][] = [
        $userId => explode(';', $values)
    ];
}

echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";
```

will output

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id_user123": [
                "123",
                "456",
                "789"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_user456": [
                "333",
                "545",
                "908"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I get this: `{"result":[[["test.php?id_user123=123","456","789&id_user456=333","545","908"]]]}` 
my php version is PHP 7.4

code: 
`$final = "test.php?id_user123=123;456;789&id_user456=333;545;908";
$result = [];
foreach ((array)$final as $userId => $values) {
    $result['result'][] = [
        $userId => explode(';', $values)
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: Ok, I see where you/we were wrong: "_I have this url_" should really be "_I have this string_". `test.php?` is part of the string, not the URL. I assumed `test.php` is the script to put the code in, `?id_user123=123;456;789&id_user456=333;545;908` the parameters

Comment: correct, I will edit the post and put string

Answer (score -2):

Simple loop with `explode()`:

```
$result = ['result' => []];

foreach ($_GET as $userId => $values) {
    $result[] = [
        $userId => explode(';', $values);
    ];
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `;` from `explode(';', $values);` and `$result[] = ...` should be `$result['result'][] = ...`

Comment: get this: `{"result":[[["171465003=4083087","25248234","26072841"...`

Comment: @spawng Pretty sure you don't get this from the URL you posted, apart from the two little adjustments from my first comment this code produces exactly what you wanted in your question

Comment: @brombeer I have tried what you fixed, but I get this: `{"result":[["test.php?id_user123=123","456","789&id_user456=333","545","908"]]}`

Comment: @spawng Double-check your URL is the one you posted in your question, cannot reproduce your result